# How to get Highlight the human body parts by tapping on body image iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have human body with head, arms, legs, and all. when i tap on head i need to show some table related to head diseases,when i touch leg same as previous one and also how i can highlight the tapped part on image.

Its like a symptom tracker in which a human body is displayed to the user and user selects any part of body , so that we can highlight the part the user elected and navigates him to some other view where a detailed data is displayed.

how to achieve this in iOS? can someone pls help me..

Comment: keep buttons at those position and do the needfull...

Answer (score 0):

Add buttons on each body part and set image for button's highlighted state and selected state and do the needfull.